# How do I reset the "@" for directories on a MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, unix, folders

```
drwx------@ 23 johnc  staff     736 Mar 30 14:31 Downloads
```

I used to be allowed to `ls -al` the contents of my Downloads directory in my $home directory.

```
$ ls -l
ls: .: Operation not permitted
```

Comment: In which directory are you when you run `ls -l .`? What is the result of `ls -l@ ~/Downloads`?

Answer (score 1):

You can clear the extended attributes with

```
xattr -c ~/Downloads
```

but you might want to inspect the extended attributes first to see what it is you're  actually clearing (`xattr ~/Downloads`).